# Unions, right to work laws

Tags: labor-economics, public-economics

Can anyone explain what right to work laws are? along with any thoughts about unions. Do they actually benefit the worker and overall market?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

For the googling part of your question:

> In the context of US labor politics, "right-to-work laws" refers to
>   state laws that prohibit union security agreements between companies
>   and labor unions. Under these laws, employees in unionized workplaces
>   are banned from negotiating contracts which require all members who
>   benefit from the union contract to contribute to the costs of union
>   representation.
>
> According to the National Right to Work Legal Defense Foundation,
>   right-to-work laws prohibit union security agreements, or agreements
>   between employers and labor unions, that govern the extent to which an
>   established union can require employees' membership, payment of union
>   dues, or fees as a condition of employment, either before or after
>   hiring. Right-to-work laws do not aim to provide general guarantee of
>   employment to people seeking work, but rather are a government ban on
>   contractual agreements between employers and union employees requiring
>   workers to pay for the costs of union representation.

read on at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-work_law).

For the second part, the thoughts about unions: this is very broad. Also it seems like you are trying to get someone else to write your homework for you? If not, it is still a broad subject and such a question is hard to answer in the SE format.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. Sadly not taking any economics classes rn.

Comment: I have never heard of this concept in economics classes.

Comment: Unions are covered usually when talking about the FEPC.